# Programatically create a-assets in A-frame

Tags: aframe

The assets in my index.html are injected on a need basis. I dont know what the assets are until a XHR request has completed.

I used the following part to generate a multi-source video asset

```
function createStreamAsset() {                                                  
var videoAsset = document.createElement("video");                           
videoAsset.setAttribute("id", "video");                                    
videoAsset.setAttribute("style", "display:none");                           
videoAsset.setAttribute("autoplay", "");                                    
videoAsset.setAttribute("loop", "");                                        
videoAsset.setAttribute("playsinline", "");                                 
videoAsset.setAttribute("webkit-playsinline", "");                          
videoAsset.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");                        


var sourceDesktop = document.createElement("source");                       
sourceDesktop.setAttribute("src", "url")
sourceDesktop.setAttribute("type", "video/mp4")                             

var sourceMobile = document.createElement("source");                        
sourceMobile.setAttribute("src", "hlsurl")
sourceMobile.setAttribute("type", "application/x-mpegurl")                  

videoAsset.appendChild(sourceDesktop);                                      
videoAsset.appendChild(sourceMobile);                                       
assetManager.appendChild(videoAsset);                                       

}
```

At the top a-assets has been appended as a child to the scene (var assetManager)

console.log prints at the top core:propertyTypes:warn "#video" asset not found.

Furtheremore, is the consturction of the video element properly done this way to match this html?

```
<video id="video" style="display:none"
        autoplay loop crossorigin="anonymous"
        playsinline webkit-playsinline
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issues by removing a pre-defined source on the object that had #video as source. After adding the assets, change the source on the object and it worked fine.